# Reading float with MATLAB socket

Tags: c, matlab, sockets

Can anyone tell me why my MATLAB code reads doubles correctly, but not floats?

### This works as expected:

Linux c server code:

```
double x = 25.2575;
write(sd, &x, sizeof(x));
```

MATLAB client code

```
t = tcpip('10.5.5.7', 50505, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
t.InputBufferSize = 8;
fopen(t);
data = swapbytes(fread(t, 1, 'double'));
```

MATLAB correctly reads in 25.2575

### This does not

Linuc c server code

```
float x = 25.2575;
write(sd, &x, sizeof(x));
```

MATLAB client code

```
t = tcpip('10.5.5.7', 50505, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
t.InputBufferSize = 4;
fopen(t);
data = swapbytes(fread(t, 1, 'float'));
```

MATLAB incorrectly reads in 6.850875536870000e-313

Comment: As `6.850875536870000e-313` is outside typical `float` range, `t` reading only 4 bytes looks insufficient to properly set it.

Comment: Setting to greater than 4 bytes gives the error Warning: Unsuccessful read:  The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.

Comment: Try sending `float x = 25.2575; double xx = x; write(sd, &xx, sizeof xx);` and reading 8.

Comment: Same error, oddly.

Comment: Nevermind, I get 2.051000000000000e-320

Comment: Just to check – have you tried `'single'` or `'float32'` in `fread`? For the `'float'` option, the documentation states "platform dependent formats are also supported but they are not guaranteed to be the same size on all platforms".

Comment: Also, you should be able to use `fread` or `fopen`'s Machine Format option to directly convert the endianness rather than using `swapbytes`.

Comment: Single gives the error: Invalid PRECISION type. float32 reads the value 6.850875536870000e-313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the swapbytes call and instead using:

```
t.ByteOrder = 'littleEndian';
```

I do not know why however.